# Приложение на Django с элементами SPA. Как реализуется?

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, spa, pjax

Часто вижу сайты, у которых на НЕКОТОРЫХ страницах реализованы spa элементы. Как это создаётся? С помощью обычной функции ajax и подобных ей или чего-то другого? Или другой вопрос, как совместить spa с mpa?

Comment: Непонятно в чём вопрос, вам никто никак не запрущает воткнуть spa-подобный скрипт в любую mpa-страницу

Comment: Ну и да, в основе абсолютно любого spa лежит какой-то ajax (впрочем, теоретически можно и вебсокет, но я таких spa в живой природе не встречал)

Comment: К примеру тот же гитхаб, это не полноценное spa приложение, но на нём есть элементы spa. Я это имел ввиду, как это реализуется? Не думаю что там используется обычные аях функции

Comment: Конечно обычные аях, потому что ничего другого в браузере тупо нет

Comment: А, ладно, я думал что-то другое. Буду знать, спасибо.